# How do i create an email this page form for my website?

Tags: php

I was looking on how to create a recommend this page form that sends the given pages URL address and where the user can enter their email address and a message however long and a single email address or multiple addresses where the user wants to send the recommend this page to.

I was wondering if anyone knew what code I could use. I am currently using PHP as my server side language.

I wanna know how to code my own form?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=php+email+form

Answer (score 1):

http://www.addthis.com/ offers a free service we've used with clients a couple of times

Comment: I've found them quite unreliable at times, but it's a good start, and really easy to plug in.  Also, any "email this" script inevitably becomes a target for spammers; better to have AddThis's mail servers deal with spammers than your own....

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty broad question but essentially to do this with PHP, you will need to be familiar with 3 things:

**$_POST** array in PHP - holds all form values on the page posted back to the server

**mail()** PHP function

**CAPTCHA** implementation for verifying real users

Updated for Frank's spammer comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking with your web host first. GoDaddy, for instance, no longer allows your script to grab the form-submitter's email as the sending email. Treats the message as spam and doesn't send it though your submitter will may get your success message.

Another option, though I haven't tried myself, is online forms at Google Docs: http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/